# Disallow form submission until PDF reaches end of document

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I am working on a policy page for my companies intranet.  There are some policies that require signoff and I need to track this accordingly.  I have seen it on sites before where form submission is disallowed until the pdf reached the end of document.  Does anyone know how to implement this?  I have done some preliminary searching online to no avail.   Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How are you showing the PDF? With JavaScript it's fairly easy to detect when the bottom of the page is reached.

Comment: Page JS cannot detect what is going on inside a PDF plugin. The pdf itself can contain JS to alert when the page is scrolled. Does it have to be a PDF?

Comment: I haven't decided on a method yet.  How could I do it in JS?

Comment: Not necessarily a PDF but needs to be easily updatable and not editable

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan, that is what I needed

Comment: Feel free to delete your question or tell me if there was a duplicate I can close with

Comment: I dont think it was duplicate, if you add your stuff as an answer I will give you cred.

Comment: Thanks but links should not be answers.